# I want to print the image in table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to print the image using ajax function but in this line it will not work the ajax function if i removed this ajax will work properly how can i fix this???

```
tbl_row += "<td><img src="<?php echo base_url().'images/'.'"+v.ad_id+"'.'/'.'"+v.ad_id+"'.'_thumb.jpg'; ?>" alt="" /></td>"
```

Comment: Haven't you forgotten ';' ???

Comment: at the end of the line

Comment: View source in your html output.  It will be clearer.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer the browser will do its best to patch up the dom errors so he may not see all the problems this way

Comment: @andrew It's not even about the DOM.  It's about not even knowing what html is being sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not escaping your double-quotes. You can escape them using the backslash (`\`)

```
tbl_row += "<td><img src=\"<?php echo base_url() . 'images/' . '" + v.ad_id + "' . '/' . '"+v.ad_id+"' . '_thumb.jpg'; ?>\" alt=\"\" /></td>";
```

Comment: <img alt="" src="<?= base_url() . 'images/' . 'AD0016' . '/' . 'AD0016' . '_thumb.jpg' ?>">  answer come like this

Comment: @user2788487 - I had assumed that you had PHP's shorttags enabled. Try my update.